# Why does Le Chatelier's Principle hold when the volume of a system is decreases?

Tags: equilibrium

I understand that when an equilibrium system is subjected to a change that it will adjust to counteract the imposed change and that thus a decrease in volume (an increase in pressure) will cause the system to shift in the direction with fewer moles of gas. But why does this work in terms of collision theory and/or kinetics?

The answer I most often see to this is that the side of the reaction with more moles of gas is 'affected more', but wouldn't the collision frequency for both reactants and products increase by the same factor and thus no shift in equilibrium?

I have tried to understand this in terms of the Arrhenius equation; k=Zρ*exp(-Ea/RT) where Z is the frequency of collisions per cubic meter, but the same problem persists. Doesn't this value of Z just increase by the same factor for both forwards and reverse reactions?

Comment: Make mental analysis of $\ce{2 A <=> B}$  with $k_\mathrm{f} \propto p^2_\ce{A}$ and $k_\mathrm{b} \propto p_\ce{B}$.

Comment: Forgive me but how do we know this? I am not so familiar with the Arrhenius equation and haven't seen anything resembling this relationship before.

Comment: The Arrhenius equation affects the temperature dependence of proportionality constants of the above proportionalities. For cases at the same temperature, we can ignore the equation. I made a mistake above, should put there rather rate: $\frac{\mathrm{d}p_\ce{\mathrm{b}}}{\mathrm{d}t} = k_\mathrm{f}(T)p_\mathrm{A}^2 - k_\mathrm{b}(T)p_\mathrm{B}$, where both kinetics constants are results of the Arrhenius equation, that are constant or T dependent.

Comment: Where can I do further reading on this subject, I still don't completely grasp why the forward k is multiplied by the square of pressure.

Comment: If the pressure of A is doubled, how would change frequency of A-A collisions?

Comment: I would think doubled, but from the equation you gave above it would increase by a factor of 4?

Comment: Think about skating people on Winter stadion, randomly colliding with each other. Now double their number. Each would collide twice more often, as there is twice as much people. But twice more often collisions with twice as many people means 4 times more collisions.

Comment: I think I kind of understand what you’re saying although it may take some thinking over. Is there somewhere I can do some further reading?

Comment: try google searching with domain narrowing term site:chem.libretexts.org  The site is dedicated on aducation texts.

Answer (score 2):

In the Arrhenius Equation, the value, Z, doesn't change with a change in volume. This is because, in collision theory, it represents the frequency of collisions at a specific or standard concentration of the species (i.e. $\pu{1.0 M}$).

One way to understand this is by using just simple forward and reverse rates. Say you have:

$$\ce{2A <=> B}$$

If the volume is decreased, and thus the pressure is increased, the equilibrium would shift right according to Le Chatelier's Principle. However, we can observe this too by breaking it into separate forward and reverse rates:

$$\ce{r_{for} = k_f[A]^2}$$
$$\ce{r_{rev} = k_r[B]}$$

Let's say the volume is halved. This means both $\ce{[A]}$ and $\ce{[B]}$ would double. However, when we consider $\ce{r_{for}}$ and $\ce{r_{rev}}$, $\ce{r_{for}}$ increases by more as the $\ce{[A]}$ is squared in the $\ce{r_{for}}$ expression. So, instantaneously after the volume decrease, $\ce{r_{for} > r_{rev}}$, which accordingly suggests that the system would shift right as previously predicted.

As this happens, $\ce{r_{for}}$ would decrease while $\ce{r_{rev}}$ would increase as more of $\ce{B}$ is formed until a new equilibrium is re-established.